# Continuity of $g$ necessary for the continuity of $f$. Why?

Tags: limits, continuity, proof-explanation

I have the functions

$g\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ any function, and be $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$ f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1 & \text {if }g(x) < 2 \\\\
3 & \text {if }g(x) \geq 2
\end{cases}
$$

If $g$ is continuous, then show that $f$ is continuous in all the points of the set $A = \{ x\in \mathbb{R} : g(x) > 2\} \cup \{x\in \mathbb{R} : g(x) < 2\}$.
Show through an example that the continuity of $g$ is necessary for the continuity of $f$.

Now I understood the first part where I have to show the general continuity, but I am having problems in understanding the solution of the second part.

Suppose we have a such $g$ function: $g(x) = 0$ for $x\neq 0$ and $g(x) = 4$ for $x=0$.

Then of course $g$ is discontinuous at zero, and so $f$ is discontinuous too at zero.

Here I got stuck. Why is $f$ discontinuous too at zero?

I meant this is what the professor writes: in the set A the continuity of g is necessary for the continuity of f.

Thank you!

Comment: "Show that the continuity of $f$... ": this means proving "$f$ continuous $\implies$ $g$ continuous", but you cannot prove propositions by means of examples...

Answer (score 1):

If $g(x) = 0$ for $x\neq 0$ and $g(x) = 4$ for $x=0$, then

$f(0)=3$ and $f(x)=1$ if $x\in \mathbb R$ is non zero.

So $f$ is not continuous at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say that that is wrong.

Say $g$ is the indicator function of the rational number set, i.e. $g(x)=1$ for rational $x$, and $0$ otherwise.

$g$ is nowhere continuous, but it is always $<2$. So $f \equiv 1$.

Comment: I edited the question, for I meant that if g is discontinuous at zero, then f is discontinuous AT ZERO too. I meant to say in the set A the continuity of g is necessary for the continuity of f

Answer (score 0):

*I meant that if g is discontinuous at zero, then f is discontinuous AT ZERO too*

Still not true. Say $g$ is the Heavyside function, $g(x)=0$ for $x<0$, $g(x)=1$ for $x\ge 0$. It's discontinuous at $0$, and $f$ is still $\equiv 1$.